# Determining the final fee from a client

Tags: fee, subxt

Is there a way to check the exact `final_fee` that the signer of an extrinsic was charged? I'd like to do so from `subxt` for monitoring purposes, but could not find this info in the `TransactionProgress` struct. If this can't be read from events, what would I have to query given the blockhash of the finalized extrinsic?

For reference, I asked the same question in the subxt repo: https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/issues/527

Answer (score 9):

Just to elaborate on this, since I've been digging into it and asking around...

We can use the following formula to calculate the `partial_fee` for an extrinsic (ie the total/final fee
minus any tip).

```
partial_fee = base_fee + len_fee + ((adjusted_weight_fee/estimated_weight)*actual_weight)
```

Where:

- `base_fee` is a fixed base fee to include some transaction in a block. It accounts
  for the work needed to verify the signature and such and is constant for any tx.
- `len_fee` is a fee paid based on the size (length in bytes) of the transaction. Longer
  transactions require more storage.
- `adjusted_weight_fee` is a fee that is itself `estimated_weight * targeted_fee_adjustment`.
  `targeted_fee_adjustment` is some adjustment made based on the network load and such, and is
  an opaque internal value we have no access to.
- `estimated_weight` is the "pre-dispatch" weight of the transaction. It's set based on the cost
  of processing the transaction on reference hardware.
- `actual_weight` is the weight that is found in the `ExtrinsicSuccess` event for the extrinsic in
  a block (it's just called `weight` in the event), and is often the same as `estimated_weight`,
  but the node has the opportunity to change it to whatever it likes, I think.

The RPC endpoint `payment_queryFeeDetails` returns `base_fee`, `len_fee` and `adjusted_weight_fee`.

The RPC endpoint `payment_queryInfo` returns `estimated_weight` (called `weight` in the response), and
a `partialFee` value, which is our best guess at the inclusion fee for the tx without actually submitting
it and seeing whether the node changes the weight/decides not to take a fee at all.

To get the correct values for some extrinsic from those endpoints, provide the extrinsic bytes, and the
block number **one before the block it made it into** (eg if the extrinsic was in block 100, you'd use
block 99 as an argument). Using the correct block number is very important.

Once you've called these endpoints, access the `ExtrinsicSuccess` event to find the `actual_weight`
(it's just called `weight` in the event props), but also a `paysFee` value which signals whether the
extrinsic actually incurred a fee at all or not (a node has the opportunity to refund the fee entirely
if it likes by setting this to `No`).

So, the steps to calculate the fee are basically:

- if `paysFee` is No, the fee paid is 0
- else, gather the values needed above and plus them into the equation above to return the final
  partial fee that was paid.

## Why the above equation?!

Well, the basic way to calculate a pre-dispatch fee is:

```
partial_fee = base_fee + len_fee + adjusted_weight_fee
```

(see above for explanations of each value).

We can obtain this result just from the `payment` RPC endpoints.

Once the extrinsic is in a block though, the `ExtrinsicSuccess` event signals whether the weight used to
calculate the fee changed (and whether we need to pay at all via `paysFee`). So we need to recalculate the
`adjusted_weight_fee` by swapping out the original `weight` it was based on with the correct weight from the
`ExtrinsicSuccess` event. That's all there really is to it.

Note that doing this calculation may incur some precision loss, and so it's recommended to use high precision
maths libraries to get the most accurate values back.

## Caveats

Substrate based chains can use whatever custom fee logic they like, and so this logic/calculation only applies to chains that copy the Polkadot fee calculation logic.

There will soon be a `transactionPayment::TransactionFeePaid` event, which will include the final fee paid for some transaction (ie the inclusion/partial fee + any tip). This will become a more reliable way to calculate fees going forwards (and is on Kusama already), but of course there is always a need to calculate fees for historic blocks too :)

Answer (score 3):

There is no event for the final fee, but you can calculate it either using the runtime API for `transaction_payment.query_info` or by executing the fee calculation from weight/length yourself. Sidecar does the latter [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar/blob/992b458/src/services/blocks/BlocksService.ts#L276L280) (note that this is an imported Rust package, just linking to its use to see the context).

Comment: This doesn't include the tip though right? where would you query that?

Comment: It is part of the signed extension in the extrinsic. But as @jsdw said, there is now an event with the fee details that makes it easier.

Comment: @joepetrowski to confirm, in order to calculate sum of transaction fees for a given day on Polkadot Relay Chain (at time of writing), one would index `TransactionPayment.TransactionFeePaid` events and parse the balance in position 1 of the list? (Position 2 is the tip?). 

Thanks!