# How do I get a Used Fee?

Tags: polkadot-js

I see this answer and recognize that `partialFee + tip = Used Fee`.

[Estimated fee and Used fee](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6361/estimated-fee-and-used-fee)

But actually it is not.

When I get the Extrinsic partialFee below, I get the Estimated Fee, not the Used Fee. Therefore, my wallet balance was misaligned with the one on the blockchain.

https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/19474756-4?tab=event

Here is how to get a partialFee.

```
const blockNumber = 19474756
const blockHash = await api.rpc.chain.getBlockHash(blockNumber)
const signedBlock = await api.rpc.chain.getBlock(blockHash)
const extrinsic = signedBlock.block.extrinsics[4]
const at = await api.at(blockHash)
const info = await at.call.transactionPaymentApi.queryInfo(extrinsic.toU8a(), extrinsic.toU8a().length)
console.log(info.partialFee)
```

[image]

How do I get a UsedFee?
Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Used fee` or aka `actual fee` is the actual transaction fee that was charged from your account for that extrinsic. This amount is emitted in an event of `transaction_payment` pallet `TransactionFeePaid`. You can see that it matches the used fee [here](https://polkadot.subscan.io/extrinsic/19474756-4?event=19474756-70). Also [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/4224/2005) is a very detailed answer how `used fee` is calculated: